# My App Metadata Rejected

Tags: ios, iphone

How can fix this issue

**App Completeness**

Your app or its metadata does not appear to include final content. Specifically, your application description does not provide sufficient information about the app content and its features.

**Next Steps**

To resolve this issue, please review your app and metadata to ensure that all of its content is final.
Since your iTunes Connect status is Metadata Rejected, we do NOT require a new binary. To revise the metadata, visit iTunes Connect to select your app and revise the desired metadata values. Once you’ve completed all changes, reply to this message in Resolution Center and we will continue the review.

**NOTE:**

Please be sure to make any metadata changes to all app localizations by selecting each specific localization and making appropriate changes.

Comment: I'm no iOS developer but I'm guessing it has something to do with the app description not providing sufficient information about the app content and its features.

Comment: you also could be missing some content on your translations if your app support more than one language.

Answer (score -1):

Change your app's description on iTunes Connect. Maybe you have to update your screenshots too. You must put subscriptions info on description field.